# How to divide the view controller screen?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am new to sprite kit. Does anyone know how to divide the view controller into two parts. One is fixed and the second one is movable (I mean like two screens)?

Comment: `UISplitViewController` displays two fixed different view controllers, but there is no built-in view controller for a free movable view controller. Your question is not specific to sprite-kit. Before you start with sprite-kit, you should take a closer look into the MVC adaption of cocoa touch.

Comment: hey there, please upvote my answer that you accepted if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do? You may not need two controllers. You can use an SKNode as a "screen" in many circumstances. I believe it's also possible to put two `SKScene` into one view.

So, what does the motionless screen do, and what does the movable screen do?

If it's something like a minimap / menu (like Nintendo DS) then you can easily do that with an `SKNode`.

You don't need two screens to "ignore" the motionless part of the screen... you get the touch inputs every frame--it's up to you what to do with them. In other words, if the user touches the non-moving part of the screen, you can just ignore those inputs.

Comment: "If it's something like a minimap . . . you can easily do that with an SKNode." How, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a UIView as a container for your whole screen and within that UIView add two SKViews which would be your "two screens" that you could do with as you needed.

You could give them the sizes you require by getting the first views height and width and set the SKViews proportionally based on that size. Such as an SKViews frame would be the parent UIViews height divided by two.